# Upload APK on playstore with same name

Tags: android, google-play

I have uploaded an app on playstore with some name and after sometime I have unpublished it. Now I want to upload a new app with same name but different package name. But playstore is showing error that the app name needs to be different.
What should I do ?

Answer (score 2):

In fact there is nothing you can do. Google Play Store package names are unique.
So all you can do is change your package name to upload the new app. Sorry, but there is no positive answer...

Comment: Yes, I know that nothing can be done. I have changed the package name but google play is not allowing me to use the same name as previous one.
Now I have solved my problem, I have updated the name of previously published app.

Comment: The package name change is required, thats what I tried to highlight with "package names are unique". I don't like this requirement either, but good to hear your problem is solved now.